# Consuming Hateoas: Non-matching JSON-request generated

Tags: java, json, spring, hateoas, spring-hateoas

Hello dear Stack Overflow!!! :)

I have a bit of a problem. I am attempting to consume a Hateoas-based application in a project and I'm having issues with Hateoas and it generating a faulty JSON-request for a test. I will provide some code examples!

Basically, I use a JSONconverter that tries to convert my request body(post) to JSON but it throws an error with what I actually get. Some information and code:

Here is my ObjectMapper that I am using:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) bean;
objectMapper.registerModules(new Jackson2HalModule());
```

Here is my converter config where I plug the objectmapper and the supported media types:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
```

Here is my RestTemplate where I plug the Jackson 2 Http Converter I just made:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate uttagRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

return builder.messageConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
```

Here is the test I run with the output:

```
mockServer.expect(requestTo(url + "/person/" + id + "/links")).andExpect(header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8.toString()))
            .andExpect(header("accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8.toString()))
            .andExpect(content().string(jsonConverter.toJson(Arrays.asList(link)))).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST)).andRespond(withSuccess());
```

Finally, here is my test output(don't mind the data, it's just test data):

```
Expected :[{"id":2112,"rel":"EZyb","href":"dspK0XickvvcMw0","type":"RaAmwWkZHlagrcQ","length":992539719,"title":"OuaRoPRClRpvprg"}]
Actual   :"[{\"id\":2112,\"rel\":\"EZyb\",\"href\":\"dspK0XickvvcMw0\",\"type\":\"RaAmwWkZHlagrcQ\",\"length\":992539719,\"title\":\"OuaRoPRClRpvprg\"}]"
```

It seems to do something really weird with the "actual" json-generated body. I'd like to have it match my expected, but no luck.

I've tried solving this, and if I remove the MediaType.HAL_JSON from my MappingJacksonConverter somehow it works in my tests, but then I can't consume the hateoas client. I need the media type there for it to work.

I've also tried writing my expected JSON with my MappingJackson writer, but it produces the exact same expected output.

Does anybody know what's going on here and can help me with this? Do you know how I may generate correct JSON-body to get the assert to work? Frankly it's doing my head in - and choosing between functioning tests without the media type and being able to consume the hateoas application with it obviously isn't an option for me. :(

Cheers for reading if you made it this far! :) Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: can you try .andExpect(content().json(link) ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what it was. With the new config, it seems that the application automatically converts to json and I didn't need to use my own jsonConverter anymore. So what was going on as basically a toJson conversion on an already jsonified object.

After removing my own jsonconverter implementation, it now functions correctly.